# How filter DataRowCollection with dateTime column

Tags: c#, .net

I need to filter a DataRowCollection to keep only entries contain "02/07/2015" (by Linq)?

I'have this DataRowCollection (planning entries)

```
Date                  HS  MS  HE  ME
02/07/2015 00:00:00   8   00  9   00
02/07/2015 00:00:00   10  00  11  00
16/07/2015 00:00:00   8   00  9   00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results =   from myRow in listEntries.AsEnumerable()
                        where myRow.Field<DateTime>("Date") == new DateTime(2015, 7, 27)
                        select myRow;
```